# How to configure Connecting Oracle Native Network Encryption with pyspark

Tags: oracle, pyspark

I need to connect to Oracle from Databricks with Pyspark.
The connection to the oracle must be by using Network Native Encryption.
Does anyone have an example?

today I am connecting like this:

```
spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", <My Orace_Url>) \
    .option("query",<My Query>) \
    .option("fetchSize","100000") \
    .option("user", <My Oracle_User>) \
    .option("password", < My Oracle_Password>) \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .option("timeout", timeout_seconds) \
    .load()`
```

How do I change it to fit Network Native Encryption?